# Pivot Time on row and Date on Column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I'll pivot date and time from 2 joined tables.

Table: Shipping

```
+-----+-------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|  ID |PartNum|ForecastTime | ForecastDate  |  ForecastNetqty |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|  1  | x001  |    8:00     |   20180101    |        5        |
|  2  | x001  |    12:00    |   20180101    |        10       |
|  3  | x002  |    12:00    |   20180102    |        15       |
|  4  | x003  |    08:00    |   20180101    |        13       |
|  5  | x003  |    12:00    |   20180103    |        12       |
|  6  | x004  |    8:00     |   20180104    |        10       |
|  7  | x004  |    12:00    |   20180104    |        5        |
|  8  | x005  |             |   20180103    |        5        |
|  9  | x005  |    8:00     |   20180104    |        13       |
|  10 | x005  |    12:00    |   20180104    |        15       |
+-----+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
```

Table: Masterdata

```
+-----+--------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|  ID |Material|    Shipto   |      DV       | CusMaterialNum |
+-----+--------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|  1  | 12345  |    11200    |     0101      |      x001      |
|  2  | 98765  |    11201    |     0202      |      x002      |
|  3  | 45678  |    11202    |     0303      |      x003      |
|  4  | 12354  |    11203    |     0404      |      x004      |
|  5  | 12365  |    11204    |     0505      |      x005      |
+-----+--------+-----------------------------+----------------+
```

I'll to this report with looping date min to max in Forecastdate

```
+-------+--------+------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|PartNUm|Material|Shipto| DV |ForecastTime|20180101|20180102|20180103|20180104|
+-------+--------+------+-----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| x001  | 12345  |11200 |0101|  08:00     |   5    |        |        |        |
|       | 12345  |11200 |0101|  12:00     |   10   |        |        |        |
| x002  | 98765  |11201 |0202|  12:00     |        |   15   |        |        |
| x003  | 45678  |11202 |0303|  8:00      |   13   |        |        |        |
|       | 45678  |11202 |0303|  12:00     |        |        |   12   |        |
| x004  | 12354  |11203 |0404|  08:00     |   5    |        |        |   10   |
|       | 12354  |11203 |0404|  12:00     |   10   |        |        |   5    |
| x005  | 12365  |11204 |0505|            |        |        |   5    |        |
|       | 12365  |11204 |0505|  8:00      |        |        |        |   13   |
|       | 12365  |11204 |0505|  12:00     |        |        |        |   15   |
+-------+--------+------+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read this to learn how to ask a good question. : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please edit your question with what you have tried so far and what is the required output.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all your dates you can use this code:

```
declare @Shipping table(  ID int ,PartNum varchar(100),ForecastTime time, ForecastDate  date,  ForecastNetqty int);
insert into @Shipping values

(  1  , 'x001'  ,    '8:00'     ,   '20180101'    ,        5        ),
(  2  , 'x001'  ,    '12:00'    ,   '20180101'    ,        10       ),
(  3  , 'x002'  ,    '12:00'    ,   '20180102'    ,        15       ),
(  4  , 'x003'  ,    '8:00'     ,   '20180101'    ,        13       ),
(  5  , 'x003'  ,    '12:00'    ,   '20180103'    ,        12       ),
(  6  , 'x004'  ,    '8:00'     ,   '20180104'    ,        10       ),
(  7  , 'x004'  ,    '12:00'    ,   '20180104'    ,        5        ),
(  8  , 'x005'  ,      null     ,   '20180103'    ,        5        ),
(  9  , 'x005'  ,    '8:00'     ,   '20180104'    ,        13       ),
(  10 , 'x005'  ,    '12:00'    ,   '20180104'    ,        15       );


declare @Masterdata table(  ID int ,Material int,    Shipto   int,      DV  varchar(100), CusMaterialNum varchar(100));
insert into @Masterdata values
(  1  , 12345  ,    11200    ,     '0101'      ,      'x001'      ),
(  2  , 98765  ,    11201    ,     '0202'      ,      'x002'      ),
(  3  , 45678  ,    11202    ,     '0303'      ,      'x003'      ),
(  4  , 12354  ,    11203    ,     '0404'      ,      'x004'      ),
(  5  , 12365  ,    11204    ,     '0505'      ,      'x005'      );


with d as
(
select s.PartNum,
       m.Material,
       m.Shipto,
       m.DV,
       s.ForecastTime,
       s.ForecastDate,
       s.ForecastNetqty
from @Shipping s join @Masterdata m
        on s.PartNum = m.CusMaterialNum
)

select *
from d pivot (sum(ForecastNetqty) for ForecastDate in ([2018-01-01], [2018-01-02],  [2018-01-03], [2018-01-04]))p;
```

If your dates are dynamic and you cannot directly write `in ([2018-01-01], [2018-01-02],  [2018-01-03], [2018-01-04])` you should use dynamic sql  to define your `in`

Comment: How to Select Min ForecastDate To Max ForecastDate in Data into Pivot Not Fox Date

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by min and max dates? You should fill the  IN with all the values that you want to be columns, and once again, if you don't know them you should construct dynamic query where first step is to determine all the SELECT DISTINCT FORCASTDATE FROM Shipping

Comment: Sorry, I'll SQL Select ForecastDate in [2018-01-01], [2018-01-02],  [2018-01-03], [2018-01-04]  By Select Min ForecastDate  to Max Forecastdate

Comment: Pivot syntax does not accept From min to max, all the columns MUST BE specified in IN, so or you do it by yourself as I did or you should write dynamic code that constructs your IN clause